# Linux gpg to encrypt a file but it does nothing?

Tags: linux, encryption

I thought this is [how](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/05/07/encrypting-files-with-password/) to encrypt a file in linux with gpg.

So,

```
xxx@xxx:~$ gpg -c /home/xxx/secretfilename.txt
```

But it does nothing but this,

```
usage: gpg [options] --symmetric [filename]
```

Any idea what this means and what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use GPG to encrypt data without sufficient understanding.  While it *can* do symmetric encryption, most use cases for GPG use public/private key encryption (see "public-key cryptography" in the FAQ), and the default CAST5 is not the best choice today.

First, try 
gpg -v --version

to see what version of gpg you're currently working with.

Then, study!

Please have the [GnuPG FAQ](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html) open for reference.

Then start with the [GnuPG MiniHOWTO](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/howtos.html)

Then refer to the [GnuPG Manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/)